# Calling a Rails JSON-API from a Bootstrap Frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, rails-api

this might be a stupid question, but can you tell me how I can call the 'endpoints' from my existing Rails JSON-API Server within my Bootstrap page.
Is it necessary, that the Bootstrap page is located in the view folder of the API server and if so how do I call the controllers and fit the received JSON into my frontend elements?

Thanks for now, I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking an scaffold of `blogs` as example with `rails routes` (`rake routes`) you can see all the "endpoints" that are defined within your `routes.rb`:

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)               blogs#index
          POST   /blogs(.:format)               blogs#create
 new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)           blogs#new
edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)      blogs#edit
     blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#show
          PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#update
          PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#update
          DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#destroy
```

If you see `blogs GET /blogs(.:format) blogs#index` is giving you all the `blogs` through a GET request.

This should bring you all the `blogs` from your API:

Using plain Javascript

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'localhost:3000/blogs', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
};
request.onerror = function() {
  ...
};
request.send();
```

Also using Javascript `fetch`:

```
fetch('localhost:3000/blogs', {
  ...
}).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response)
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err)
});
```

Using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'localhost:3000/blogs',
  dataType: 'script',
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result)
  },
});
```

Then you can continue inserting, updating and/or removing data as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at `rake routes` which would show you the available routes.

So essentially would be making a request client side, maybe in some js to a particular endpoint, and then that endpoint would return data with which you could do whatever you want client-side.

You most likely wouldn't be calling your endpoints from within your views, typically you would have a separate js file, but if you really wanted to, could add some js to your views and call your endpoints directly from there.